# How to achieve same height of two overlapping div with two different positionning?

Tags: html, css, css-position

index2.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='menuFrame'>
        </div>
        <div id='banner'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

index2.css :

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#menuFrame {
    content: "";
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: fixed;
}
#banner {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}
```

I want a fixed always-on-top div and an overlapping scrollable div.
The width is set right for both but not the height.

Can't also get why to display empty div it's different : &nbsp / content: = ""... but I can live with that.

---

**EDIT** : when I change

> height: 10%

with

> height: 50px

for both div I get what I want... why ?

http://jsfiddle.net/axj3yocz/

Comment: I would suggest put one div inside other and change its position to absolute.

Comment: why not use javascript to set div height attribute equals?

Comment: @SSS just tried, no improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.. forget from the first answer.

so after I tested your code in jsfiddle, I added a position:fixed, to both of the divs.
and this result "one" div but with mixed color.

you can check on http://jsfiddle.net/

put this on the css textbox:

```
    body {
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
   }
   #menuFrame {
       content: "";
       height: 10%;
       width: 100%;
       background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
       position: fixed;
   }
   #banner {
       height: 10%;
       width: 100%;
       background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
       position:fixed;
   }
```

and this on the html area:

```
    <div id='menuFrame'>
    </div>
    <div id='banner'>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
```

I'm not sure if this is the result you want.. so check this on jsfiddle

Update:

try this:

```
      body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
      }
      #menuFrame {
            content: "";
            height: 10%;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
      #banner {
            height: 10%;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
            position:fixed;
     }
```

it gives one div with mixed colors (the colors of both divs)

Comment: They're not overlapping. That's why I needed one to be position: fixed.

Comment: see what happen if you're adding "position:fixed" to container div, i think this will answer your problem

Comment: Still not, sorry. I want to achieve this : http://jsfiddle.net/axj3yocz/ except I want the height to be in percentage not in pixel.

Comment: Getting closer :). The only difference is that I want one to be fixed but not the second one like in my jsfiddle. So that when I'll scroll down one of these two div will stay at the top of the csreen.

Comment: update my answer, but there is a funny thing, when you use my way you get a different color

Comment: Strange (actually not my second color is blue yours is green)... see comment above, just wrote it one second before yours.

Comment: hi, did you have any success in this ?

Comment: Nope :(... still stuck. Can't figure why this : http://jsfiddle.net/ert4r2ok/ is not working while : http://jsfiddle.net/axj3yocz is working!

Comment: Sorry about that.   http://jsfiddle.net/nr6hg4pm/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ert4r2ok/   The only difference is the change of both height parameters from 50px to 10%... and the result is messed up.

Comment: so.. did you succeed?

Comment: Same place as in my comment of Aug 27 at 8:34, no other ideas :) ?

Comment: The difference between your updated solution and http://jsfiddle.net/nr6hg4pm/ is just that 'position:"fixed";' does not go well with 'content:"";'... anyway thanks a lot Elior ! Still don't completely get why tough.